# mod_rewrite rules for clean URLs with optional parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the current URL:

```
http://domain.com
```

When you visit this URL it by default loads:

```
http://domain.com/index.php
```

In my .htaccess I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L]
```

The .htaccess gives 404 for all pages so Im sure its wrong.

I want to be able to have all of the following URLS work

```
http://domian.com/val1/
http://domian.com/val1/val2/
http://domian.com/val1/val2/val3
http://domian.com/val1/val2/val3/val4/
http://domian.com/val1/val2/val3/val4/val5
```

Meaning they are optional parameters

What am i doing wrong? How can I set up .htaccess to accept optional parameters.

**EDIT:** I had to many questions in the original question so I just made it into one more easily understandtable question. Hopefully Ill get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found the answer after quite a bit of trial and error:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?word=$1&media=$2&date=$3&sortby=$4&source=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?word=$1&media=$2&date=$3&sortby=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?word=$1&media=$2&date=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?word=$1&media=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?word=$1 [L]
```

This gets me the results I was looking for. However if there is a slash at the end I get a 404
example:

```
http://domain.com/val1/
```

Gives a 404 however

```
http://domain.com/val1
```

Works as expected. How come?

**EDIT:** faa solution for trailing slashes worked. Final rules look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Test my answer. The reason `http://domain.com/val1/` doesn't work with your rules, is explained there and corrected. You need to add an optional trailing slash to the regex. Like this `/?$`. It's all in my answer.

Comment: Your answer gave me an interner server error. Your trailing slash solution worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: I guess it is because the rules in your original question are in a different order. I didn't test them, though. Just wanted to point out the reason for the error.

Comment: Your answer was very helpfull. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There is a trailing slash in some of the request examples that the regex in the rules are not matching.

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var1=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I posted the answer that worked for me. will adding NC fix the new issue Im having?