# Clean URL with multiple variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I plan to receive a number of urls. What mod rewrite rules would I use to make the following conversions for incoming urls:

```
http://domain.com/i/ => 
http://domain.com/index.php

http://domain.com/i/b/233223/c/23333 => 
http://domain.com/index.php?b=233223&c=23333

http://domain.com/i/dd/9844kjhf/fj/djP756/ee/kjhKJH => 
http://domain.com/index.php?dd=9844kjhf&fj=djP756&ee=kjhKJH

http://domain.com/r/ => 
http://domain.com/restore.php

http://domain.com/w/place/chicago =>
http://domain.com/withold.php?place=chicago

http://domain.com/w/ =>
http://domain.com/withold.php
```

Basically, the first portion after the domain corresponds to a page, the rest is a set of any number of parameters to be passed.

Comment: have you already tried it yourself wit .htaccess?

Comment: yes, the idea is to use htaccess, but the issue I'm having trouble with is using the first part after domain to correspond to any number of pages (as specified in an array in htaccess??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
# If the URI is just /i/, rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^i/?$ /index.php [L]

# If the URI is /i/ plus some paths, rewrite the paths into query string and let rewrite engine loop
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$ /i$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will take as many path nodes as the [internal recursion limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) is set to, by default it's 10. That means by default you can have up to 9 sets of parameters unless you up this limit. So:

```
http://example.com/i/a/1/b/2/c/3/d/4/e/5/f/6/g/7/h/8/j/9
```

will first match the 2nd rule, and continue to loop:

```
1. /i/b/2/c/3/d/4/e/5/f/6/g/7/h/8/j/9?a=1
2. /i/c/3/d/4/e/5/f/6/g/7/h/8/j/9?b=2&a=1
3. /i/d/4/e/5/f/6/g/7/h/8/j/9?c=3&b=2&a=1
4. /i/e/5/f/6/g/7/h/8/j/9?d=4&c=3&b=2&a=1
etc.
```

until finally you're left with

```
/i?j=9&h=8&g=7&f=6&e=5&d=4&c=3&b=2&a=1
```

and the first rule gets applied and you should finally end up with:

```
/index.php?j=9&h=8&g=7&f=6&e=5&d=4&c=3&b=2&a=1
```

Comment: this works, thx, but what happens if a new page is specified, instead of /i/b2/c3 there is /newfile/b2/c3 ?

Comment: @Adrian33 then you need to change the `i/` to `newfile/` in the two rules

Answer (score 1):

As you could have an unlimited number of parameters in your URL it would be better to create a script in you application to parse them.

You could use .htaccess to direct all incoing requests to a routing file ( e.g. index.php )

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then run something like [PHP explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to parse the URL

Comment: I wonder if it'd help to have multiple cases in the htaccess file -- 1 parameter, 2 parameters, 3 parameters, 4 parameters (and avoid a routing file)

Comment: something like this may work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735590/mod-rewrite-rules-for-clean-urls-with-optional-parameters

Comment: you could do but what if you wanted 20 parameters? then u have to rewrite mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: yep. I got an answer but only for up to 5 params and 1 page name, it's about 7 lines.